# Remove default applet menu

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I'm working on a JApplet, but I want a custom menu. When I insert this menu, I still get the applet menu and below my own menu.

```
package multiformat;
import ui.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class CalculatorMVC extends JApplet{

        Command command;                // het model
        JTextField input;

        public void init()
        {
            resize(250,200);

            // Maak het model
             Calculator calc=new Calculator();

            // Maak de controller en geef hem het model
            command = new Command(calc);
            input = new JTextField();
            input.setHorizontalAlignment(input.RIGHT);

            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
            menuBar.add(menu);
            JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
            menuBar.add(help);
            // Create a menu item
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Label");
            //item.addActionListener(actionListener);
            menu.add(item);

    //      this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            getContentPane().add(input, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            getContentPane().add(command,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

In this case both menu's show up. My own and the default from applet. How can I remove the default from applet?

Answer (score 5):

A small hack to remove the applet viewer menu bar for applets:

- During testing.
- Launched free floating using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).
- Dragged from a page in the browser.  (Actually you might need to change it for that, since at the time `init()` is called, the applet is still embedded in the page and there is no applet viewer frame from which to remove the menu bar.)

[image: SneakyApplet]

```
//<applet code='SneakyApplet' width=400 height=30></applet>
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SneakyApplet extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        add(new JLabel("Look ma!  No Menu!"));
        Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
        for (Frame frame : frames) {
            frame.setMenuBar(null);
            frame.pack();
        }
    }
}
```

#### To compile & show

```
prompt> javac SneakyApplet.java
prompt> appletviewer SneakyApplet.java
```

Comment: huh, I assumed access to `Frame.getFrames()` would be restricted to return only the frames created by the applet, but seems that `appletviewer` is not so carefully implemented. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Applets don't have a default menubar. Do you mean the menubar of the `appletviewer` utility? There is no way to remove it because the frame is not created by the applet; in the same way you cannot remove the menubar from a web browser that would eventually host the applet.

**Edit** I was wrong, see Andrew's answer.